# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error de esta librería FinanceJs cuando uso uno de sus métodos (TIR)?

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una trabajo y necesito obtener el `VAN` y el `TIR` y estoy intentando usar una librería llamada [FinanceJS](http://financejs.org/)

**Como se usa según la documentación:**

```
var finance = new Finance();
// To calculate Amortization

finance.AM(20000, 7.5, 5, 0);
// => 400.76
```

entonces lo pruebo en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

funciona correctamente.

En la pagina esta como utilizar cada uno de sus métodos, existen muchos pero solo ocupo 2 de esos de los cuales el `VAN` si me funciona pero el que me da problema es el `TIR`

**Ejemplo del `VAN`**

```
  finance.NPV(10, -500000, 200000, 300000, 200000);
  => 80015.03
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora utilizo el `TIR`
esto es lo que me dice la documentación como lo debo usar:

```
finance.IRR(-500000, 200000, 300000, 200000);
=> 18.82
```

y me manda estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código JS de esa parte donde me marca error:

```
// Internal Rate of Return (IRR)
Finance.prototype.IRR = function(cfs) {
var depth = cfs.depth;
var args = cfs.cashFlow;
var numberOfTries = 1;
// Cash flow values must contain at least one positive value and one negative value
var positive, negative;
Array.prototype.slice.call(args).forEach(function (value) { //Aquí marca el error
  if (value > 0) positive = true;
  if (value < 0) negative = true;
})
if (!positive || !negative) throw new Error('TIR requiere al menos un valor positivo y un valor 
negativo');
function npv(rate) {
  numberOfTries++;
  if (numberOfTries > depth) {
    throw new Error('no puede encontrar un resultado');
  }
var rrate = (1 + rate / 100);
var npv = args[0];
for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
  npv += (args[i] / Math.pow(rrate, i));
}
return npv;
}
return Math.round(seekZero(npv) * 100) / 100;
};
```

Si alguien uso esa librería en algún momento o si conocen una que cumpla con lo que necesito si me podría recomendar, Gracias.

el problema en realidad es el `TIR` el `VAN` de hecho ese lo hice con `Javascript` el `TIR` es mas complejo para mi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar, resulta que la ultima versión de esa librería le hicieron algunos cambios y en esos cambios modificaron el **`IRR = TIR`**  y otros **2** mas pero sin hacer las pruebas de funcionamiento (me imagino). entonces me dirigí al código de esa librería en **Github** y pensé en utilizar una versión antes de la que estaba usando, y eso fue lo que me soluciono el problema.
[repositorio](https://github.com/ebradyjobory/finance.js/tree/f53d8eaf9f710187d89510c98f90391aaa37c6ad)